# angularjs: invoking custom filter from within controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to manipulate some JSON data using a custom angular filter and I'm having difficulty when trying to invoke it from within my controller.

As you can see in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kc8ehyne/6/), the idea is to only return items from my json with a rating higher than 6, which should return two items: items 2 & 3.

This is my filter:

```
.filter('greaterThan', function() {
    return function(a, b) {
        return parseInt(a) > parseInt(b);
    }
})
```

and I'm invoking it within my controller like so:

```
 var greaterThanFilter = $filter('greaterThan'),
     filteredItems = greaterThanFilter(data, {'rating': 6});

     $scope.items = filteredItems;
```

I've tried to model my filter and the invocation on the [built-in angular filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You probably need something like in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nr7vwsvx/

Comment: Another alternative is to use the third argument to the `filter` filter (i.e. the comparator), in addition to specifying what object property you want to compare on in the argument prior (i.e. `{'rating': 6}`). _Filter_ definitions in Angular are somewhat misleading. They should probably be called _Formatters_ or something similar instead. (See https://jsfiddle.net/p27q6erz/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not implementing the filter the way you think you are, it looks like you're sorting, but what?

This is probably more like what you are looking for, note the **options** parameter.

```
  .filter('greaterThan', function() {
    return function(data, options) {
      var result = [];
      data = data || [];
      if (options.rating != undefined) {        
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
          if (data[i].rating > options.rating)
            result.push(data[i]);
      } 
      return result;
    }
  })
```

And in your controller, invoke like this

```
$scope.items = $filter('greaterThan')(data, {rating: 6});
```

I forked your fiddle, [see this](https://jsfiddle.net/rpkr4ej7/1/)